# Unable to call a text file and change text in html using Ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I am testing to see if I am able to call a text file and change my text in the html file using Ajax. The html file and the text file are both in the same directory on the server.

But the text is not changing when I click on it, as in the txt file is not opening. Please advice if you spot any mistake. Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState===4 && xmlhttp.status===200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","info.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv"><h2>This text will change to text in file</h2></div>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

The text file simple contains the following text:

> IT WORKS!! THIS WAS LOADED FROM THE TEXT FILE!!

Comment: Open your devtools in chrome or firebug and check the network results.  Does the file at least get loaded?  I put this on my server and it's giving me a forbidden 403 response.

Comment: ajax wont work on local machine - if your address bar in browser looks like "file://" and not "http://" ... maybe that helps.

Comment: I am running this at a web host at the public_html folder.

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine.  The text file must not be in the same folder as your html file or the server you are using is blocking.  Open up the developer console and watch the network response to see if you are getting 404 error.

http://plnkr.co/edit/V5tKVKPjYLvjFJWE475Y

Comment: Hm text file cant be at same place as html file? At pinkr where you are testing it, I see both files at same place. I honestly don't think the server is blocking anything considering the files are available locally. When I try to just connect to another .php file at same folder, it works. Just not happening with this text file.

Comment: I connect via this line for the .php file: <?php include 'test.php'; ?>

Comment: Both text file and the html file should be in the same directory.  You should be able to access the text file by just typing in the url.  What is the url for your test page?

Comment: First of all, your program is asking for ajax_info.txt and getting a 404 error. GET http://kuttykilly.net46.net/ajax_info.txt 404 (Not Found)

Comment: I do have the file ajax_info.txt in the same directory with the same text as info.txt. It doesn't return a 404 error.

Comment: Might have confused with previous statements. Sorry for that. Testing page:  kuttykilly.net46.net/AjaxTest.html                             txt file url: http://kuttykilly.net46.net/ajax_info.txt

Comment: If you type url kuttykilly.net46.net/ajax_info.txt directly on the browser, you should see the text show up on your window.  It doesn't because there is a 404 error.  Either the file is not where you think it is or the server blocking.

Comment: Request URL:http://kuttykilly.net46.net/ajax_info.txt
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found

Comment: It's weird really. Cos when I try to ender a url where I don't have a file for example: http://kuttykilly.net46.net/something.txt I get a 404 error. when I enter http://kuttykilly.net46.net/ajax_info.txt I get no error. Just a blank white page. Double checked and it is in same directory as the AjaxTest.html file.